# How to select records Composite Primary key and Foreign key reference (many to many relationship)

Tags: mysql

I am tyring to learn composite Primary Key and Foregin Key. Wherein I am trying to have many to many mappings. Have three tables here.

```
CREATE  TABLE  authors(
  authorID INT PRIMARY  KEY ,
  firstName VARCHAR(20),
  lastName VARCHAR(20),
  gender VARCHAR(20)
);


CREATE  TABLE  books(
  bookId INT PRIMARY  KEY ,
  bookTitle VARCHAR(20),
  price INT,
  publisher VARCHAR(20)
);


/*Junction table*/
CREATE  table authors_Books(
  authorId INT NOT NULL,
  bookId INT NOT NULL ,
  FOREIGN KEY (authorID)
    REFERENCES authors(authorID),
  FOREIGN KEY (bookId)
    REFERENCES books(bookId)
 );
```

The records inserted are

Authors Table:

```
insert into authors values (1,'Mark','Dunn', 'Male');
insert into authors values (2,'Sara','Longhorn', 'Female');
insert into authors values (3,'Jessica','Dale', 'Female');
insert into authors values (4,'Steve','Wicht', 'Male');
```

Books Table

```
insert into books values(1,'Learn SQL', 10,1);
insert into books values(2,'Learn C#', 20,1);
insert into books values(3,'Learn CSS', 15,1);
insert into books values(4,'Learn HTML', 20,0);
```

Authors books Table

```
insert into authors_Books values(1,1);
insert into authors_Books values(1,2);
insert into authors_Books values(2,1);
```

We can observe that the author Mark Dunn has written two books (Lean SQL and Learn C#). Also, the book Learn SQL is written by two authors Mark Dunn and Sara Longhorn.  How do I write an SQL query to get the books written by Mark? I assume that we can get results without using joins right?

I have tried this query but it's not correct

```
select 
  books.bookTitle, 
  books.price, 
  books.publisher, 
  authors.firstName, 
  authors.lastName 
from 
  books, 
  authors, 
  authors_Books 
where 
  authors_Books.authorId=1 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write query without join but need condition in "Where", like that:

```
select 
  books.bookTitle, 
  books.price, 
  books.publisher, 
  authors.firstName, 
  authors.lastName 
from 
  books, 
  authors, 
  authors_Books 
where 
  authors_Books.authorId=1 
  and authors.authorID = authors_Books.authorId
  and authors_Books.bookId = books.bookId
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine and works as expected. But could you please explain to me how the and conditions are working? 

I tried giving only the first and condition. I observerd that it fetches all the books twice having the frist and last name  as Mark Dunn

Comment: this solution is instead of "INNER JOIN", please note that while the syntax above works great and still produces similar efficient results for Inner Join and Cross Join, it is not preferred ANSI standard syntax. It is suggested that for clarity of the code and to follow the standard, it is a good idea to use the explicit JOIN Keywords.

Comment: I think you should still use "JOIN" syntax. try this instead https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins